# Build Hybrid/ionic app code using fastlane

Tags: ionic3, fastlane

i am trying to build Hybrid/ionic app using `fastlane` but when i build it is asking `.xcodeproj` or `.xcworkspace` file path, but in my hybrid app project folders doesn't have the `.xcodeproj` or `.xcworkspace` file, how can i build this project please help me

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to follow the instructions at https://ionic.zone/fastlane

But on the other hand, your Cordova app should definitely have an `xcodeproj` file in `platforms/ios`.